# How can I only insert Materialize Carousel in my Angular Project?

Tags: angular, carousel, materialize

I'm trying to insert a Materialize carousel to my Angular project, but when I do, other stuff from Angular Material doesn't seem to work properly. How can I only import the necesarry stuff for the carousel (I just need that component).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Import everything you need into your module, let the compiler do the rest. You shouldn't bother with that.

Comment: Thanks, I got it figured out :)